Displacement and position vectors
I know that displacement vector means a change in the position vector of a body and also that change in displacement vector and change in position vector are not the same thing, but if we talk about a really small time interval, say $\mathrm{d}t$, then can we say that the change in displacement vector will be the same as the change in position vector?

The displacement vector IS the change (shift) of the position vector:
$$\vec{D} = \Delta \vec{r}$$
So the change of the displacement vector is the change of the change of the position vector.
It is different if you express it using the RATE of change of the position, $\vec{v}$. In that case the relation:
$$\Delta \vec{r}=\vec{D} =  \vec{v}\Delta t $$ is true only for small enough times, or in the scenario of constant rate of change for the position (constant velocity)

This isn't true. The displacement isn't the same as velocity.

I didn't state anywhere that the displacement is the velocity

I said that the displacement is the change (NOT the rate of change) of the position, which is its definition (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_(geometry))

Yes. The position vector is the sum of the displacement vector and the position vector of the starting point, which is a constant. Since they only differ by a constant, they have the same rate of change. In fact, this means that they have the same change over any finite time interval as well.
